# In typescript, how to declare a type which is a mapping from an enum to some other value so that it allows missing keys?

Tags: typescript, enums

Given a typescript enum, how to declare a type which is a mapping from the enum keys to some other type while allowing missing out on some keys of the enum. For example here I want to create a mapping from Color to number but I may choose to leave out one or more of the colors.

**Edit:**
I tried to use a **Map** instead of a **Record** and it seems to work fine. What causes this behaviour and why is typescript doing this because conceptually they seem the same to me.

```
enum Color { // Given typescript enum like this
  RED = 'RED',
  BLUE = 'BLUE',
  GREEN = 'GREEN',
}

// Why does this complain that I am missing GREEN ?
const record: Record<Color, number> = {
  [Color.RED]: 1,
  [Color.BLUE]: 2,
};

// This is fine
const map: Map<Color, number> = new Map([
  [Color.RED, 1],
  [Color.BLUE, 2],
  // doesn't complain about GREEN being missing
]);
```

Comment: `Record` and `Map` are different data structures so they have different behavior.  Presumably you want to use `Partial<Record<K, V>>` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NrEzVw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplicate target; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it does although I want to know the exact difference

Comment: I know that they have different behaviours in terms of what can be keys, remembering the insertion order, etc etc off the top of my head although I don't understand why they have to be different in this regard ?

Comment: The exact difference?  `Record<K, V>` is a TypeScript type corresponding to a plain JavaScript object, and the other is [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is a class with its own methods and behaviors.  Note that the question as asked doesn't say "I want to know the exact difference between `Record` and `Map`" which would be a second question.  Currently the question seems to be "how to declare a type ... allowing missing out on some keys of the enum" Which one are you really trying to ask here?

Comment: Yeah I got sidetracked for a bit. This answers my question